# L2 Norm: Unfamiliar notation

Tags: notation, normed-spaces, spectral-theory, orthogonal-polynomials

In [this article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-246X.2005.02625.x/abstract) that I am reading, I am given a non-negative spectral function $w(\lambda)$ which is "interpreted as a weight function determining the scalar product of two functions $f(\lambda)$ and $g(\lambda)$" where
$$(f,g) := \int_0^\infty w(\lambda)f(\lambda)g(\lambda)\;\;d\lambda.$$

Here $f(\lambda)$ and $g(\lambda)$ are functions of the class $L_w^2(0,\infty)$. If all moments of the spectral function exist then we can construct a set of orthogonal polynomials $p_n(\lambda)$ such that
$$(p_m,p_n) = h_n\delta_{mn}$$
where $\delta_{nm}$ is the Kronecker delta and $h_n$ is the $L_w^2(0,\infty)$ norm of $p_n(\lambda)$.

I have not seen this norm notation before. What is the significance of the $w$ subscript? How would you write this norm out as a summation?

Apologies if this question has been asked but I have looked and can't seem to find this notation.

Comment: $w$ is probably some weight or density. More context would be helpful.

Comment: I assume that the $w$ subscript is simply to indicate that $L^2$ under this weighted inner product and the corresponding induced norm is not the same space as $L^2$ under the usual inner product and norm. Regarding how to write the norm, it would simply be $\|f\| = (f,f)^{1/2}$ as usual, but using the weighted inner product formula you cited in the first paragraph.

Comment: For a general positive measure, it is standard to refer to the linear space of measurable functions on $X$ for which $\int_{\Omega} |f|^2d\mu < \infty$ as $L^2_{\mu}(\Omega)$, and the inner product is $(f,g)=\int f(\omega)\overline{g(\omega)}d\mu(\omega)$. When the space $\Omega$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the measure $d\mu = w dm$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure, then it is also standard to use the notation $L^2_{w}(\Omega)$.